# Bootstrap Carousel makes Html5 video flicker on chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, bootstrap-carousel

Can anyone explain to me why this `Bootstrap Carousel` makes the HTML5 video flicker on google chrome? Every time the carousel changes image the video below flickers, I don't understand what is wrong with this, it has something to do with the class "embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" on the video wrapper, as when I remove the class the issue stops happening but I need to have a responsive video on the page.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zREPqP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><video src="//player.vimeo.com/external/159873222.hd.mp4?s=54c0141dd1e7ab5a78a2fda1d69a9f011c89bf42&amp;profile_id=113" poster="http://cletadmin.git-staging.clet.edu.au/assets/images/video/why-study.jpg" controls="controls" width="300" height="150"></video></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Steps to reproduce:* open the above link on chrome and let the slider play, don't hit play on the video just observe it flashing from poster image to grey background.

Comment: Everything works fine with your code when I tried it on my Chrome and even on Firefox, nothing flickered. There wasn't any effect on the video-flickering thing even when I removed the mentioned class 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9' Can you update your Chrome, if not.

Comment: don't play the video let it sit on the screen and look at the poster image

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, I never played the video. :) Anyway, I would have probably downloaded the CSS file locally, found out the mentioned CSS class and see what isn't working for both classes 'embed-responsive' & 'embed-responsive-16by9'  Thanks!

Comment: embed and responsive are classes from bootstrap, i'm pretty sure that has nothing to do with styles it's more of a js from bootstrap that resizes the video to the right aspect ration accordion to screen size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it worked with:

```
.embed-responsive {
    z-index:1000
}
```

Comment: don't need to be z-index:1000, it worked with index 1 for me ;) thanks!